# How to program a series of different tasks? SMACH?

Tags: actionlib, smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am wondering how I can learn my robot to execute a series of tasks.

Like this example:
First:  move to a position on map
Second: say something
Third:  move to docking station

I came across SMACH and built a state machine.
But when it comes to actions and sending goals like PoseWithCovarianceStamped, I don't know how to do it. I looked through some tutorials but it didn't help me a lot.

Also the switching between C++ and Python is a bit annoying to me, because I practically programme C++ and don't really know Python.

Is it an acceptable solution to just have a main.cpp and use "if" clauses as a "state machine"?
So I can programme all in C++?

Help appreciated :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12348/how-to-program-a-series-of-different-tasks?-smach?/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2011-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can certainly program state machines in C++. There are several techniques, amd it is not particularly hard.

Smach is a nice interface, however. It provides several tools you are unlikely to come up with on your own.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2011-12-14**:
Thanks, I think I will stick with C++, besides you know a good tutorial where sending a goal in a state machine in python is shown ;)

**Comment by [AlexandrosNic](https://answers.ros.org/users/45283/alexandrosnic/) on 2021-05-06**:
After a decade I still have the same question: Is there any example with which we can call our .cpp scripts from the SMACH .py file?